# How to add muc component without restarting the prosody server

Tags: module, configuration, lua, multiuserchat, prosody-im

To add muc component without restarting the prosody server
done the following code then trying to execute it using rest api. 
but muc component not able to loading .

```
--------------code begin---------------
localh hm = require "core.hostmanager";
local mm = require "core.modulemanager";

host= "muc.example.co";
hm.activate(host);
local key= "component_module";
local value = "muc";
cmg._M.set(host, key, value);
mm.load_modules_for_host(host);

-----code end-----------------
```

How can we enable muc service point without reloading the prosody server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below code we can able achieve it

```
local muc_host= "test.example.com"
local hm = require "core.hostmanager";
local cmg = require "core.configmanager";
local append_text= 'Component "'..muc_host..'" "muc" \n'

            --appending the text to config file
            local file_name="/etc/prosody/prosody.cfg.lua"
            file = io.open(file_name, "a")
            file:write(append_text)
            file:close()
            -- load & activate new muc server
            local lstatus=cmg.load(file_name)
            local new_server_status = hm.activate(muc_host)
            mm.load_modules_for_host(host)
```